# SQL Server : group by with conditon and give to function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table `Test` with a column `Name` in SQL Server:

```
Name
-----
a
a
a
c
c
b
```

I wrote this query:

```
select *
from (select Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
      from Test
      group by Name 
      having COUNT(*) > 2) as newTbl
where dbo.fn_Test(Name) = 1
```

Where `dbo.fn_Test` a SQL Server scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Test]
   (@name nvarchar)
RETURNS bigint
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count int

    SET @count = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
                  FROM Tbl
                  WHERE Name  = @name);
    return @count;
END
```

From first query `FROM` part is plain that this select get:

```
select Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
from Test
group by Name 
having COUNT(*) > 2
```

Output:

```
Name cnt
--------
 a    3
```

But when debug the query and enter to the `dbo.fn_Test` function it work for all names:

```
a b c
```

So how to create select in order to get only name "a" in function?

Comment: what is the structure of "Tbl" table ? Should it be Test instead of Tbl in the function?  And one more question: I understand what each statement or SQL object does but what are you trying to obtain, "generally" speaking with the above work?

Comment: Tbl any table. When I debug my script and enter the function part by logic I shold get name only 'a', but I get other names. Why? The function content don't important.

Comment: Can you update the where clause like so "dbo.fn_Test(newTbl.Name) = 1" and retry? (notice prefixing the inline view alias before the column name).

Comment: I try It but again in function I get all name values.

Answer (score 1):

insert you first select into #t

```
insert into #t 
select Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
      from Test
      group by Name 
      having COUNT(*) > 2)
```

and then use cursor to call the func

```
...select dbo.fn_Test(@cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Name,Count(Name) from test
Group by Name 
having Count(Name)>2
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. This is my solution.

```
select Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
into #tmpTbl
from Tbl
group by Name 
having COUNT(*) >  2


select *
from #tmpTbl
where dbo.fn_Test(Name) = 1
```

And in fn_Test function I get Names which is correspond to conditions.